# salesforce soap api in soapui

Tags: soap, salesforce, soapui

I am trying to consume my service class of salsforce SOAP API in SOAPUI. 
Getting the error

```
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>'false' is not a valid value for the enum 'LogCategory'</faultstring>
      </soapenv:Fault>
```

What should be specific value in

```
         <pay:categories>
            <pay:category>false</pay:category>
            <pay:level></pay:level>
         </pay:categories>
         <pay:debugLevel></pay:debugLevel>
```

Comment: You can also validate the request from the request editor using `Alt+v` key combinations or right click and validate.

Answer (score 0):

from [this page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/sforce_api_header_debuggingheader.htm) it looks like `pay:category` has to be one of

- Db
- Workflow
- Validation
- Callout
- Apex_code
- Apex_profiling
- All

Comment: no problem. You might, you know, accept my answer? :)